# How do I locate a button in Dialog box in vc++

Tags: mfc

How to locate a button in dialog box?

```
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();   
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedCancel();   
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
    CButton m_Button;    
    BOOL DialogNew::OnInitDialog()
    {
        m_Button = GetDlgItem()    
    }
};
```

Comment: And do what with it?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I think I am missing how to use member variables..but what are they exactly and how are they linked with controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, most of the time you don't need member functions to interact with buttons in a dialog.  Most of the time, you can get by with ON_BN_CLICKED) message handlers in your derived class message map.  If you really want to create a member variable, then initialize it in DoDataExchange().  The Visual Studio wizards will help you do that.  Here is some sample pseudo-code for a dialog that has a message map with a handler for the click of the IDC_BUTTON1 and also initializes a variable for it.  If you look at the header file where DDX_Control is defined, you will see other nifty DDX_ functions like DDX_Text, DDX_Check, and DDX_Radio.

```
class CMyDialog : public CDialog
{
public:
 /// blah, blah, blah....
   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
   void OnClickThatButton();

   void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX); // initialize controls in dialogs in DoDataExchange()
protected:
   CButton m_Button;
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
   ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, OnClickThatButton)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyDialog::OnClickThatButton()
{
   AfxMessageBox(_T("put your functionality here.");
}

void CMyDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
   DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON1, m_Button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a member variable like m_Button or a message handler function like OnBnClickedButton1 you should do it using the IDE wizards, which add a bit of magic code to make these things functional.

I'm not sure what your question means, but a book or a tutorial on MFC would be a good start. Here are two tutorials:

http://www.functionx.com/visualc/

http://www.tenouk.com/cplusplusnmfc.html

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, member variables allow you to name an instance of a control object so that you can call its member methods later on.  You don't need member variables to work with a control.  However, they do make things easier.  I would caution you in the use of GetDlgItem () as it returns a **temporary** pointer to the control and may not be valid the next time you use it.  If you want to use member variables (and you should when you can), follow the advice given by *ScottMcP-MVP*.